# Appcelerator: Problems with long strings inside a label

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-studio, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I am having a big problem setting a really long text on appcelerator, two things are happening, first the scrollview is not scrolling, and the text is being truncated by a "...", and if I set the label height it goes blank and disappears.

```
    function popup() {
// Popup
var window = $.cadastrarPessoa;
var view = Titanium.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor : "#80000000",
    top : 10,
    left : 10,
    right: 10,
    bottom: 10,
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    borderRadius: 20
});
var confirmButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Confirmar',
    backgroundColor: "#00000000",
    bottom: 0,
    width: "50%",
    height: 50,
    left: 0,
    borderColor: "#00000000",
    borderWidth: 1
});
var cancelButton = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    title: 'Cancelar',
    backgroundColor: "#00000000",
    bottom: 0,
    width: "50%",
    height: 50,
    right: 0,
    borderColor: "#00000000",
    borderWidth: 1
});
var label= Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    top: 10,
    right: 10,
    left: 10,
    bottom: 60,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In necessitatibus asperiores explicabo aut laborum quam ut labore iste sit quaerat optio voluptatibus incidunt quod suscipit nemo ea quo, impedit veniam ullam consequatur enim sapiente inventore officia nulla minus. Magnam consequatur, molestias, aliquid aspernatur vero voluptatibus reprehenderit tempora! Recusandae cum praesentium, quidem autem quo impedit dignissimos ea nostrum aspernatur in, iure perferendis voluptate similique rerum, deleniti quaerat perspiciatis molestiae dolorem cupiditate commodi corporis! Libero eveniet illum dolorem nobis, repudiandae excepturi rerum, nulla consequuntur alias aliquam error quos tenetur pariatur illo et ducimus facere, quas atque officia in laborum perferendis tempora. Ab, tempore dolores corporis fuga, laborum reprehenderit culpa ipsum nobis saepe, voluptatibus expedita? Totam ratione consectetur reiciendis adipisci ab veritatis itaque quae laborum id delectus perspiciatis ipsam aspernatur qui, vitae eligendi voluptatum numquam facere provident et eum? Reprehenderit illo doloremque, facilis at! Unde quo, doloribus nemo numquam ducimus esse alias veritatis fugit. Error rem aut consequatur. Odit illo omnis ipsa ullam dolorum velit animi laboriosam expedita! Nesciunt, ab, unde! Tenetur itaque similique illo ipsa iusto nemo beatae nostrum soluta iste dicta quia rerum aut blanditiis at, minima eaque autem quasi nihil. Voluptatum doloribus earum animi vel iure a optio aspernatur adipisci nulla. Non atque quis ea hic odio autem ipsa fuga ducimus in eaque! Dolorem quis eius et illo nulla quaerat sint delectus iusto illum ut minus, assumenda id sequi earum repellendus error similique voluptate sed nisi vitae exercitationem. Dignissimos ipsum itaque unde eius aliquid facilis tempora, ad soluta possimus excepturi aperiam, dolorum pariatur voluptate. Quia, quos dolorum, sit reiciendis id voluptas, nemo similique provident, voluptatum in deserunt expedita quae tenetur! Sit fuga quis, soluta sed, amet laborum aspernatur optio voluptatibus blanditiis necessitatibus fugit dicta eos, et libero officia esse! Obcaecati amet, nihil, sapiente nobis magni, sit, inventore excepturi odio iure numquam reiciendis! Dolorem nobis architecto ut a. Vel sequi cum recusandae sit quasi nostrum aut quam, laborum quaerat error? Repellat in nemo earum corporis soluta dignissimos, beatae amet, accusamus deserunt recusandae harum, nesciunt cumque quas assumenda consectetur illum eum nihil vel porro. Aperiam omnis ea fugit expedita nulla, reprehenderit animi quidem accusamus ducimus veniam quisquam nesciunt quis vitae voluptas sequi, delectus pariatur culpa totam dolore repellat error, non? Ad ipsa debitis deserunt voluptatem aut quis aliquid quae iure. Commodi, dolor adipisci recusandae vero expedita sapiente distinctio vitae natus. Vel dolor veniam facilis distinctio. Doloremque nisi repellat, enim sapiente nemo tempore non repudiandae facere. Ipsa voluptas minus, dolores ipsam libero animi rerum earum cumque est modi provident eius perspiciatis incidunt. Necessitatibus dolore odio beatae molestias, possimus quaerat dolor quibusdam ratione laborum aspernatur, porro tenetur consectetur reiciendis recusandae, temporibus, quod nihil facilis distinctio et natus deleniti. Veniam cumque, debitis labore, provident aliquam maxime magni voluptatibus. Dignissimos mollitia impedit voluptatem soluta accusamus hic itaque, adipisci, doloremque, recusandae sequi omnis fugit voluptas. Itaque tempora repudiandae, non earum assumenda, laudantium fugit dolorem doloremque voluptates hic quaerat ducimus distinctio. Odio, laborum! Deleniti officia incidunt nesciunt soluta minus amet maiores perspiciatis sunt, debitis magni ipsum, officiis molestiae, animi distinctio dignissimos! Modi laborum soluta, fugit ipsum nihil autem voluptatum. Quisquam blanditiis ipsum a quae quos eveniet numquam tenetur odio, iusto reiciendis officiis, unde esse aliquid provident hic ullam assumenda, culpa qui at distinctio magni et eos autem. Minima totam numquam eveniet voluptatem dolorem, autem cumque deserunt harum doloremque omnis minus odio voluptas impedit quod alias molestiae mollitia? Optio officiis dicta deserunt commodi quisquam, dignissimos dolores perspiciatis, consequatur officia at dolor voluptate sequi iste vitae. Odit a dolorem consequatur corporis nihil, dicta repudiandae vitae adipisci laudantium cumque similique atque tenetur ab obcaecati enim dignissimos veritatis numquam quod inventore mollitia consequuntur possimus ut maiores. Illum tempore eaque blanditiis tempora perspiciatis nemo esse, corporis reiciendis deleniti vel adipisci expedita temporibus repellat et eligendi, autem facere assumenda ullam aliquam vero cupiditate non laborum cum explicabo. Beatae architecto quo, odio sint eaque quaerat amet adipisci expedita eveniet error cum natus hic saepe quae odit, quidem laborum facere, velit aliquid! Temporibus a, quaerat accusamus. Quibusdam dolore inventore pariatur, non officiis harum perferendis, debitis repellat temporibus quisquam facilis error, nobis tempora dignissimos voluptate quaerat officia veniam consequuntur consequatur similique deleniti. Porro veniam illo id quod modi a provident officia tempore atque deleniti delectus soluta, rerum, facere iure itaque ratione esse ullam quam reprehenderit cumque nisi! Similique voluptatum sint nulla ex sunt harum odio maiores, consectetur, cum architecto, magnam doloremque itaque exercitationem quo animi, voluptas assumenda libero necessitatibus beatae iste temporibus fuga maxime quia nam? Laborum dicta voluptate, ab earum. Beatae, saepe eius, a aperiam neque accusantium ea, ut quas ipsam error voluptates ab quod atque? Minima veritatis quasi molestias ipsa, vitae expedita! ",
    font: {
        fontSize:8    
    }

});
var textView = Ti.UI.createView({
    height: '100000px',
    width: Ti.UI.FILL
});
var scrollable = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    views:[textView],
     scrollType:'vertical'
});

textView.add(label);

view.add(scrollable);
window.add(view);

scrollable.add(label);

view.add(confirmButton);

view.add(cancelButton); 
    }
```

By just firing my "popup" function the screen appears but the scroll does not work and the text gets truncated on the size of the view.

[the screenshot showing how the text ends, it happens both in android and iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aXGH.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just make a ScrollView instead of view

```
var textView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    width: Ti.UI.FILL
});
```

Comment: thank you very much, also I forgot to put the scrollview height, and the scrollView won't scroll without it, and also doing so, the text is not being cropped anymore.